# Mongoose saving with objectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save comments for a post. When I POST a comment from client side, the comment should be saved with the ObjectId of the post, which I collect from the post page - req.body.objectId. I have tried the method below, but it only gives me VALIDATION ERROR.

MODEL

```
var Comment = db.model('Comment', {
    postId: {type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'},
    contents: {type: String, required: true}
}
```

POST

```
router.post('/api/comment', function(req, res, next){
    var ObjectId = db.Types.ObjectId; 
    var comment = new Comment({
        postId: new ObjectId(req.body.objectId),
        contents: 'contents'
    }
```

How can I achieve this? and Is this the right way to implement such functionality? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not proper way of inserting reference typed values.

You have to do it like,

```
router.post('/api/comment', function(req, res, next){
    var comment = new Comment({
        postId: db.Types.ObjectId(req.body.objectId),
        contents: 'contents'
    }
```

It will work as you desired.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use **mongoose.Types.ObjectId()** method to convert String representation of an Object ID to an actual Object ID

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post('/api/comment', function(req, res, next){
    var comment = new Comment({
        postId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.objectId),
        contents: 'contents'
    })
}
```